# VLC-python don't read my mp4 video online

Tags: python, stream, streaming, vlc

I'm just looking for a way to read video from internet with Vlc-python.
i have just a very simple script but it does not work with my video and i don't understand why it's working for some link and why not others...

```
# importing vlc module
import vlc

  
# creating vlc media player object
media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
  
# media resource locator
#First link it's woring
#mrl = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
#Second link it does not work 
mrl = "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"  

# setting mrl to the media player
media_player.set_mrl(mrl)
  
# start playing video
media_player.play()
```

I'm look all the day for a solution but i don't find it...
So i hope that someone can help me
As always i would like to thanks all the people who works and help the others here !
Sorry for my bad english, i'm french X)

Comment: Can you download that file and watch it manually instead of using python? That link might be broken.

Comment: It's working for me, it's from this web-site : https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-video-files/sample-mp4-files/
It's the samething for  this link : https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-30s.mp4